# when I run the query I get this error: ORA-06550

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

i have this error when i run this query.

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Query:

```
DECLARE
v_flag_tipo_factu varchar2(20);

BEGIN
  SELECT valor_param INTO v_flag_tipo_factu FROM t_param WHERE cod_param = 
  'TIPOFAC';

if v_flag_tipo_factu = 'FN' THEN 
    SELECT
        substr('00' || to_char(cta.cod_correo), -2) ||
        substr('000000000' || to_char(cta.num_cta_cte), -9) ||
        substr('000000000' || to_char(max(distinct fac.num_fac)),- 9)
    FROM
        t_acc_const cta,
        t_fac fac
    WHERE
        cta.num_cta_cte    = fac.num_cta_cte   AND
        fac.num_factura    < 900000000
    GROUP BY cta.cod_correo, cta.num_cta_cte;
end if;
END;
```

I expect 240,000 results like this:

```
13000291956000774037
06000167340000223372
13000089241000246480
13000057283000105163
06001632092003471840
13000093581000257191
12000252313001947873
06000120216000066999
06000309294001948770
13000192054000285006
```

Comment: As error states, inside a PL/SQL block it's neccesary to store the data returned by queries in some variable, using the `into` sintax.

Comment: Read the manual. Specifically [Select Into](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't like the PL/SQL rules, where the queries must be stored in variables for each step, you could use a query like this which should return the same

```
with v as (
  SELECT valor_param FROM t_param WHERE cod_param = 'TIPOFAC'
)
SELECT
  substr('00' || to_char(cta.cod_correo), -2) ||
  substr('000000000' || to_char(cta.num_cta_cte), -9) ||
  substr('000000000' || to_char(max(distinct fac.num_fac)),- 9)
FROM
  t_acc_const cta,
  t_fac fac
WHERE
  cta.num_cta_cte    = fac.num_cta_cte   AND
  fac.num_factura    < 900000000 AND
  EXISTS (select 1 from v where valor_param = 'FN')
GROUP BY cta.cod_correo, cta.num_cta_cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you were told, `SELECT` (the one inside the `IF`) lacks in then `INTO` clause. You'll have to declare one more local variable and use it:

```
DECLARE
  v_flag_tipo_factu varchar2(20);
  --
  v_result varchar2(50);                           --> this
BEGIN
  SELECT valor_param INTO v_flag_tipo_factu FROM t_param WHERE cod_param = 
  'TIPOFAC';

if v_flag_tipo_factu = 'FN' THEN 
    SELECT
        substr('00' || to_char(cta.cod_correo), -2) ||
        substr('000000000' || to_char(cta.num_cta_cte), -9) ||
        substr('000000000' || to_char(max(distinct fac.num_fac)),- 9)
    INTO v_result                                  --> this
    FROM
    ...
```

It'll work if that `select` returns a single value; otherwise, query will raise

- `no_data_found` if there are no rows that satisfy conditions
- `too_many_rows`. How to handle it? It depends on what you want to do ...

Comment: this query return 241338 results like this 13000291956000774037

Comment: It means that you can't select that into a scalar variable. What do you plan to do with 240.000 rows? Maybe using a cursor FOR LOOP "solves" the problem (as you'll handle each row separately)? Or, (bulk) selecting into a collection? As I said, it just depends on what you want to do.